# Splitting Columns in USQL

Tags: u-sql

I am new to USQL and I am having a hard time splitting a column from the rest of my file. With my EXTRACTOR I declared 4 columns because my file is split into 4 pipes. However, I want to remove one of the columns I declared from the file. How do I do this?

The Json column of my file is what I want to split off and make you new object that does not include it. Basically splitting Date, Status, PriceNotification into the @result. This is what I have so far:

```
@input =
  EXTRACT
     Date string,
     Condition string,
     Price string,
     Json string
  FROM @in
  USING Extractor.Cvs;

@result = 
  SELECT Json
  FROM @input

OUTPUT @input
TO @out
USING Outputters.Cvs();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I have misunderstood your question, but you can simply list the columns you want in the `SELECT` statement, eg

```
@input =
  EXTRACT
     Date string,
     Status string,
     PriceNotification string,
     Json string
  FROM @in
  USING Extractor.Text('|');

@result = 
  SELECT Date, Status, PriceNotification         
  FROM @input;

OUTPUT @result
TO @out
USING Outputters.Cvs();
```

NB I have switched the variable in your `OUTPUT` statement to be `@result`.  If this does not answer your question, please post some sample data and expected results.

Comment: sure no problem wBob